# How to average count column but by specific occupations

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, average

[image: Result from current query]

I'm currently doing an assignment for a SQL class and can't seem to figure out how to go on from this. Going on from what I have I can't seem to average the counts per occupation. With what I have so far I see how many books each person borrowed. If I try to average the column it just averages everything together when I need it specifically by occupation. Also, I Grouped by clientId because each client has multiple books borrowed.

The assignment is The average number of borrowed books by job title.

Borrower Table:

```
BorrowId(PK), ClientId(FK), BookId, BorrowDate
```

Client Table:

```
ClientId(PK), ClientFirstName, ClientLastName, ClientDoB, Occupation
```

This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT **, count(*)
FROM borrower
INNER JOIN client on borrower.ClientId = client.ClientId
GROUP BY borrower.ClientId
```

Here is what I get from the query that I have so far. My goal is to average these counts by occupation. So, for example, I want it to show

| Occupation | Avg of occupation |
| --- | --- |
| Bus Driver | 4 (14/4) |
| Cashier | 5 |
| Computer Engineer | 3 (6/2) |
| Computer Programmer | 5.666 (17/3) |

Comment: What result set you got and how it's wrong?

Comment: what is this double star * *?

Comment: Sorry, the double star is a mistake and my results so far only show the count for each person. I need to average the count by each occupation.

Comment: Please add sample data for both tables, and then show us the output you expect.  Until you have done this, you have not asked a complete question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First aggregate only in the table `Borrower` to get the counts and then join to `Client` to get the average per `Occupation`:

```
SELECT c.Occupation, AVG(b.counter) average_count
FROM Client c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ClientId, COUNT(*) counter
  FROM Borrower
  GROUP BY ClientId
) b ON b.ClientId = c.ClientId
GROUP BY c.Occupation;
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is pretty simple:

```
SELECT Occupation, count(*) BooksBorrowed
FROM Borrower
NATURAL LEFT JOIN Clients
GROUP BY Occupation;
```

[SQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/0980eeb037c04b8694a05ee3fd31ca96/)

You just need to join tables and calculate count with group by occupation.

Comment: This solution gives me just the total count for each occupation but I need the average for each occupation.

Comment: Using the query written I did small change, can you tell me if this can help, https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/54c842fe796efe1be948c1145ee7446f/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the average number of borrowed books from all occupations, then use:

```
SELECT AVG(num_books)
FROM 
(
    SELECT COUNT(b.ClientId) AS num_books
    FROM client c
    LEFT JOIN borrower b ON b.ClientId = c.ClientId
    GROUP c.Occupation
) t;
```

The idea here is that each record in the intermediate subquery aliased as `t` above corresponds to the book count for a certain occupation.  We then wrap that query and just take the average of all the counts to get the overall average book count.

Comment: This returns one row of an average for all occupations included. I need to find the average per occupation.

Comment: You just need to add occupation to the select statement.  This will then do the average per occupation.

Comment: @GCJ Actually, adding the occupation to the select clause is moot.  The group by clause determines the group used for aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

INNER JOIN will help find the average count

```
SELECT Occupation as Jobtitle, count(*) as BooksBorrowed 
FROM Borrower 
NATURAL INNER JOIN Clients 
GROUP BY Occupation;
```